# How to pass instance getter as function parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to C# so please explain in layman's terms or please point out to relevant documentation I can read and understand.

I have an integer variable defined like this:

```
public int myCount => SomeList?.Count(p => !p.IsOnline) ?? 0;
```

What I want to do is to pass `MyCount` in a function call:

```
ICommand myCommand = new DebouncedCommand(execute: async tcs => await myService.DoSomething(myCount));
```

Where the signature of `DoSomething` is:

```
public async Task DoSomething(int myCount) { if (myCount <= 10) { .... } }
```

`myCount` is coming always as 0 inside `DoSomething`.

So what I understand is that the following line

```
public int myCount => SomeList?.Count(p => !p.IsOnline) ?? 0;
```

is a short hand of instance getter. And instead of passing `myCount` as a plain integer (which is not working), I want to pass the instance getter as lambda or `Action` delegate.

However, being new, I am not able to figure out how to do this. How will my signature change? And how do I use it inside my method. i.e. how will `if (myCount <= 10)` change ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `SomeList` is not null or has any items where `IsOnline == true`?

Comment: @JohanP Yes. SomeList keeps getting updated. So in the case when SomeList has values, even then the value of count keeps being 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the reason for your 0 count is because of code you have not shown. The code you have shown does what you are hoping it should do. My best guess on that is that you have another local variable for myCount or a local SomeList that points to a distinct list. Perhaps passing `this.myCount` explicitly will tell you if that is what you have accidentally done.

Answering the second part of the question, you are after a Func rather than an action.

Your call needs to pass in a method that returns myCount. The following is a simple way to do that:

```
        myService.DoSomething(()=>this.myCount);
```

Your method signature needs to accept a method that returns an int, then you can call Invoke() on that Func to get the result.

```
    public void DoSomething(Func<int> myCountFunc)
    { 
        if (myCountFunc.Invoke() <= 10) 
        {
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the part you have not specified here. Is your application multi-threaded?

Look at this:

[image]

It works because the call to function happens again and so the getter is reevaluated.

Let me know if you have multi threading, I will update the solution then.

Comment: Yes.. it is multithreaded. The signature of `DoSomething` is actually `public async Task DoSomething(` and the call is like: `ICommand myCommand = new DebouncedCommand(execute: async tcs => await myService.DoSomething(myCount))`

Answer (score 0):

This syntax;

```cs
public int myCount => ... ;
```

Is just shorthand for

```cs
public int myCount {
    get {
        ... ;
    }
}
```

So your example is getting the current value of myCount, which invokes the `get` above, then pass that int as an argument to the method.

```cs
myService.DoSomething(myCount);
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below regarding it being multi-threaded.

Comment: Could you update your question to include that structure?

Comment: I have updated my question. Apologies for that. I am extremely new with C#.

Comment: I think my point still holds. The "current" value of your property will be evaluated immediately before `DoSomething` is executed. Which will happen when `DebouncedCommand` invokes that execute parameter. Put a breakpoint on the property getter and look at the stack trace.

Comment: A "simplified" example https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5lqZwB0AKgKYAeALvihlgKx3IB2AhgLbkDOADuwDG5dACEANuwAWyAN7J0izDHQAxAPbqFS+UiX70fAE4BLAG7tqIrADZ0J1tXSsqTgLzpUdA0qgBme0d0ADV2cQBXETcAPnQwMBcaFj0fTACoOwARdQBldW5qKQcAcwAKByczAEp0GMwbYgBhfL5xcitgDOTUtPr0Zs5OdlZgUqhGAB4M2J589qLWYpq62YKFsqrvVO0ffz6KHmpSqp2DXR79cambGbnCktrMAA50Y9rYqABOdGy8tZLSqEIuRNshTj0oAB2fr5IYjUqreYlUEpHwAX1OGKQWKAA=== removing most of the async code. Note how the compiled async lamda accesses the property `<>4__this.DoSomething(<>4__this.Value)` as you would expect.